# Grab all users who have last logged in between two dates in another table

Tags: mysql

I want to grab all users that have **last** logged in between two specific days. How can this be done?

**Note**: the reason why I did `sub.updated_at` is because:

1. the login session may last for more than a day
2. same users may log in on different pc and start a secondary session
3. I need to get the very last session started by the user and then check when it was last updated.

Example build: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39849/11

So from the example on sqlfiddle I would expect the query to select `Bill`, because `updated_at`, for his last record, is between `2019-09-15 00:00:00` and  `2019-09-15 23:59:59`. One of `John's` entries was also updated between those dates but his latest record was updated on `2019-09-18 12:00:00` hence why John should not be selected.

---

This is a possible solution, but I have concerns about performance, indexing `update_at` should have a positive effect, but what if we have 1mil+ users and an even greater number of user logins:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM `user_logins`
        WHERE `updated_at` >= '2019-09-15 00:00:00'
        ORDER BY `user_logins`.`id`  DESC
    ) as sub 
    GROUP BY `sub`.user_id
) as sub 
WHERE `sub`.updated_at BETWEEN '2019-09-15 00:00:00' and '2019-09-15 23:59:59'
```

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `user_logins`
    WHERE `updated_at` BETWEEN '2019-09-15 00:00:00' and '2019-09-15 23:59:59'
    ORDER BY `user_logins`.`id`  DESC
) as sub 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM user_logins
        WHERE user_id = sub.user_id
            and updated_at > '2019-09-15 23:59:59'
    );
```

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1):

You query may be simplified to -

```
SELECT U.*, UL.*
FROM users U
JOIN user_logins UL ON U.id = UL.user_id
JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(updated_at) updated_at
      FROM user_logins
      GROUP BY user_id) UL2 ON UL2.updated_at = UL.updated_at
                            AND UL2.user_id = UL.user_id
WHERE DATE(UL2.updated_at) BETWEEN DATE('2019-09-15 00:00:00') AND DATE('2019-09-15 23:59:59')
ORDER BY UL.id DESC
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39849/62) is the fiddle.

Comment: This query grabs single user and i need to grab all users who fit the criteria.

Comment: So,  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39849/1, from fiddles example, if i was to use your query, excluding limit, i would select both Tim and John if updated_at was between `2019-09-15 00:00:00` and `2019-09-15 23:59:59`. Instead of just Tim.

Comment: @user3402600, I have updated the query. Please try now. Here is the updated fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39849/55

Comment: Thanks for that Ankit, however, your query still selects John.

Comment: Did you see the fiddle in the comment? it is perfectly selecting both the records.

Comment: Yes, i have. It should only be selecting Tim

Comment: You need only tim or the fiddle in answer is giving you only Tim?

Comment: I need only Tim to be returned

Comment: That's pretty good, thanks... the use of subqueries within join didn't pass my mind. One thing to note,  `JOIN user_logins UL ON U.id = UL.user_id` cause query to scan the whole table, which will cause issues once users table grows.

Comment: @user3402600, When table grows this much so that it creates performance issues, You can have indexes or partitioning on the table to improve performance. BTW if this answer solves your problem, Please consider up-voting and accept.